# Proving the chain A/B≅A/C≅X

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the following groups:

$$  A=\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2},
 B=\{0,2\}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2},
 C=\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\{0\} $$

I would like to prove:

1. $A/B\cong A/C$.
2. $B\not \cong C$.

In order to do so, I need to find $X$ so $A/B\cong A/C\cong X$. At start I though that $X=\mathbb{Z}_2$ but I can't to seem to prove that $A/B\cong X$. How to find $X$?

Comment: Don't $A/B$ and $A/C$ both have order $2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think they do. then $X=\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @abuka123: Not equal; just isomorphic, because that is the only group of order 2 (up to isomorphism).